# Stripe Connect error 'No such merchant'

Tags: payment-gateway, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am processing payments using Stripe Connect and the client ID that is meant to receive payments from my application is returning the error "No such merchant: ca_8xxx". 
My code is :

```
try {
  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $amount, 
    "currency" => "usd",
    "source" => $token,
    "description" => "Strike Charge",
    "application_fee" => 500,
    "destination" => $client_id //not working
    ));
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
  // The card has been declined
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When [charging through the platform](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees#charging-through-the-platform), the `destination` parameter should be set to the ID of the connected account on behalf of which you're processing the charge. Account IDs look like `acct_...`.

Right now it looks like you're passing your platform's `client_id`. The `client_id` is used when [connecting users](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts#connecting-users) with the OAuth flow.